# Customize parsing in react-navigation params

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using react-navigation with react-native.

I know that I can customize how `JSON.stringify` serializes my class into JSON. I am doing this because some of the properties of my class are Dayjs objects from day.js which give the non-serializable warning in Expo Go.

I need to be able to handle the `JSON.parse` side of that. I realize that `JSON.parse` uses a reviver function, but is there any way that I can provide such a function to react-native when it parses my params?

I'm really not sure why react-navigate can't (or doesn't) store these objects in memory. Why the serialization?

Comment: give some code ?

Comment: @MahammadMomin, I'm asking how to do something. I haven't written any code yet. The code for react-navigation is open-source, I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen if you are passing non-serializable values such as class instances, functions etc. in params. React Navigation warns you in this case because this can break other functionality such state persistence, deep linking, etc.

In the official documentation, they said that the params you pass are JSON-serializable. That way, you'll be able to use state persistence and your screen components will have the right contract for implementing deep linking.

You can refer this: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/troubleshooting/#i-get-the-warning-non-serializable-values-were-found-in-the-navigation-state

Comment: I am aware of all of this. This is not quite what I asked. I'm not using deep linking or functions. So, I will just ignore this warning. That doesn't feel like a solution, but that is JavaScript. Thanks.